# Does a flight training company need to make a copy of my driver's license?

Tags: light-sport-aircraft

I want to get a Sport Pilot license, but the company that will train me wants to make a copy of my driver's license. I don't mind showing it, but is a copy required?

Comment: They usually want to keep a copy for legal purposes. they may ask for information to prove that you are a citizen and may be required to keep it on file.

Comment: Are you a US citizen?

Comment: Are you saying you want to get a Sport Pilot license because of identity theft issues? Or are you concerned about identify theft if the company retains a copy of your DL?

Answer (score 8):

According to 49 CFR 1552.3 a flight school is required to keep a copy of the documents used to provide proof of citizenship for five years. This is usually a passport or birth certificate. A driver's licenses is not proof of citizenship in the US.

However, a valid photo ID (such as a driver's license) is required in addition to your pilot's license in order to exercise the privileges of the pilot's certificate because the FAA issued pilot's licenses do not have a photo for identification. So a business that is renting an aircraft to you has a legitimate interest in retaining evidence that they are handing over their valuable asset to a licensed pilot, and that you are who you say you are.

They may not be required to keep a copy of your driver's license, but they are also not required to rent you an aircraft or provide flight instruction.

Comment: "valid photo ID is required in addition to your pilot's license because the FAA issued pilot's licenses do not have a photo for identification" only while exercising the privileges of the pilot's certificate

Comment: @SteveKuo correct!

Answer (score 6):

A driver's license does not establish citizenship, but does establish identity for TSA.  TSA has records requirements which instructors and schools must follow for flight training customers. Normally proof is provided by birth certificate or passport, and the school or flight instructor is required to keep a copy.  If  a birth certificate is used, a government issued photo ID is required, which is normally a driver's license, but does not have to be, if you have some other government issued photo ID (in my case I have an airport ID, which is photo ID issued by a local government).

To be clear, a driver's license does not serve the TSA citizenship documentation requirement.

However, FAA pilot certificates require photo ID for identification. For many people, a state issued driver's license is used.

Additionally, the school is entitled to keep records of certificates which you have, and in the case of sport pilot, the state issued driver's license acts as a medical certificate.

Finally, the school's insurance may require that certain records of students be retained. While that may not be a legal requirement, it is a practical one.

Comment: A drivers license does not establish identity in all states. The TSA only accepts drivers licenses from states that are [REAL ID compliant](https://www.dhs.gov/real-id)